# How to dualize a theorem by Eilenberg and Moore about monad, comonad and adjunction?

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, adjoint-functors, monads

Eilenberg and Moore have shown that given a monad $L$, if $L$ has right adjoint $R$, then $R$ is a comonad.

I see how to dualize this result to obtain the following theorem: given a comonad $R$, if $R$ has left adjoint $L$, then $L$ is a monad. Indeed it suffices to notice that an adjunction $L \dashv R$ dualizes to $R^\text{op} \dashv L^\text{op}$.

But at the bottom of [page 7 of this paper](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dao7/drafts/monad-or-comonad-orchard11-draft.pdf#page=7), it is written that it also "*easily*" dualizes to the following theorem: given a comonad $L$, if $L$ has right adjoint $R$, then $R$ is a monad. How to make this easy dualization?

Comment: Presumably what's meant by "easily" is that the proof in the next paragraph isn't too hard. I don't think it means that it's trivial (i.e. via replacing $\mathcal C$ with its opposite).

Comment: @SCappella So this is not a dualization, is it?

Comment: Not exactly. Parts of the statement are dualized (monad <-> comonad) but other parts aren't (right adjoint stays right adjoint). It might be possible to generalize the statements so that they are related by a duality.

Comment: @SCappella Any idea how to "*generalize the statements so that they are related by a duality*"?

Comment: I'm not completely sure. You'd need to introduce a second category so that one part can be dualized but not the other.

Comment: Alternatively, going to 2-categories would give you multiple ways to dualize (i.e. not only $^{op}$ but also $^{co}$ and $^{coop}$).

Comment: As I said on the other question, I encourage you to look into [string diagrams](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7220). It is a notation making for instance very obvious the way to go from a monad structure to a comonad structure on the adjoint. If it is a right adjoint, you bend on the right, and if it's a left adjoint, you bend on the left.

Comment: @Idéophage This would correspond to my second paragraph. But it says nothing about the third paragraph.

Comment: I will post an answer and try to make drawings. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\mathcal K$ be a $2$-category. A monad in $\mathcal K$ is an object $C$ together with a $1$-morphism $T \colon C \to C$ and $2$-morphisms $\eta \colon 1 \to T$ and $\mu \colon TT \to T$ as well as some commuting diagrams (see [the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#monads)). Comonads can be similarly defined.

Similarly, adjunctions can be defined internally to any $2$-category. A right adjoint to a $1$-morphism $L \colon C \to D$ is a $1$-morphism $R \colon D \to C$ with a unit and counit making the usual diagrams commute (modulo coherence isomorphisms).

Given that a monad structure on $L$ yields a comonad structure on any right adjoint $R$, we can get all four possible dualizations by switching out $\mathcal K$ for its duals.

You can check that a monad structure on $T$ in $\mathcal K^{co}$ ($2$-morphisms are reversed) is the same as a comonad structure on $T$ in $\mathcal K$. This also dualizes adjoints: if $L \dashv R$ in $\mathcal K^{co}$ then $R \dashv L$ in $\mathcal K$.

Interestingly, switching to $\mathcal K^{op}$ only dualizes adjoints: if $L \dashv R$ in $\mathcal K^{op}$ ($1$-morphisms are reversed), then $R \dashv L$ in $\mathcal K$.

To dualize only monads, we can use $\mathcal K^{coop}$ (both kinds of arrows are reversed).

---

Some more details, as requested. Suppose we're given an ordinary comonad $L$ and $L$ has an ordinary right adjoint $R$. We'd like to conclude that $R$ is a monad by applying the theorem that given a monad $L$ and a right adjoint $R$, $R$ is a comonad.

More specifically, we're going to apply the *general $2$-category* version of that theorem. We need to start with a monad, but right now we have a comonad. To switch between them, we'll work with $\mathcal {Cat}^{co}$ instead. This means that we have a comonad now, but also switches the adjunctions, so that our comonad has a left adjoint. (Doing just this step is equivalent to switching out the category for its opposite, i.e. the trivial duality).

Thus, we need to dualize again in a way that unswaps adjoints, but leaves monads unchanged. Taking the $^{op}$ of the $2$-category accomplishes that, so now we're working in $\mathcal {Cat}^{coop}$.

To spell that out explicitly, if we're given an ordinary comonad $L$ and an ordinary right adjoint $R$, then this same data is equivalently a monad $L$ and a right adjoint $R$ in $\mathcal {Cat}^{coop}$. Then applying the general theorem, we get a comonad structure on $R$ in $\mathcal {Cat}^{coop}$, which translates back to a monad structure on $R$ in in $\mathcal {Cat}$, i.e., an ordinary monad.

Comment: I have little experience with 2-categories, thus I have trouble applying your answer to the 2-category **Cat** that is of concern in my question. Can you spell it out?

Comment: @Bob, I've added some details.

Comment: Great! This is clear now. Thanks. However, this assumes that the "*general theorem*" is true. But, as far as I know, Eilenberg and Moore proved it in the $2$-category **Cat**, not in any $2$-category $\mathcal K$.

Comment: @Bob That's true, but the general proof is almost exactly the same. Just a couple extra structural isomorphisms inserted in places.

Comment: Is it impossible to adapt this trick it using 1-categories only?

Comment: @Bob Never say never, but I don't really think so, at least not in a way that reuses the same proof exactly. Still, it's just a matter of reversing arrows (either the direction of the functors or the direction of the morphisms), so the same proof works with the right adjustments. But without the mechanism of the opposite $2$-category, you still need to check all the details (commuting diagrams, etc.). It's not an "easy" corollary.

Comment: In the second part of your answer, you apply the general 2-categorical result to the special case of *small* categories. It is possible because they form a 2-category. But how to deal with *locally small* categories? The problem I see with them is that they do not form a bicategory.

Comment: @Bob That kind of question is best answered with universes. Let U and V be universes. We can form the 2-category of U-locally small, V-small categories (which will live in a universe that contains V). Then take the $^{op}$, $^{co}$ and $^{coop}$ of this 2-category to get all the corresponding theorems.

Comment: I understand what are universes. But what is the meaning of "the 2-category of U-locally small, V-small categories"?

Comment: @Bob Each individual hom set lives in U (U-locally small, or perhaps locally U-small, depending on naming conventions), but the category as a whole lives in V (V-small).

Comment: If I understand well, you agree that the locally small categories do not form a 2-category, right? So you propose to build a larger 2-category that will contain as objects not only locally small categories, but also larger categories. And then "take the op, co and coop of this [larger] 2-category to get all the corresponding theorems" in the case of locally small categories. That's it?

Comment: @Bob It's a *smaller* category. All locally small categories would form a proper class (assuming your ambient theory has such things), so instead we define something that acts like the category of locally small categories, but is parameterized by two universes to control what's meant by "locally small" (that's U) and to bound the sizes of the categories we consider (that's V).

Comment: I have posted [a new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632847) about this. I wish you could explain in an answer there what you mean by "the 2-category of U-locally small, V-small categories".

Answer (score 1):

We can see things more clearly using [string diagram](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7220) notation. I did not find how to draw them here (no tikz allowed) so I had to resort to images scan.

A monad structure on $T : C→C$ is given by a pair of natural transformations as below, satisfying certain axioms.

[image: monad structure]

Suppose $G$ is a right adjoint to $T$. This is given by a pair of natural transformations as below satisfying the [triangle identities](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities).

[image: adjunction]

Using these, we can "bend" the monad structure on $T$ to get a comonad structure on $G$ as follows (rest to check the axioms).

[image: bend to the left]

Now, if $G$ is a *left* adjoint to $T$, we can do the "bending" the other way around:

[image: bend to the right]

This corresponds to what is said in the answer of SCappelia: we have a "formal" theorem working in any $2$-category. We have an up-down symmetry but also a left-right symmetry, making 4 versions in total.

Comment: On the first diagram, I understand that the right part is the multiplication, but why are there two occurrences of T in the left part?

Comment: Aaah you are right. I mixed things up with the unit of an adjunction, sorry! I redo the drawings.

Comment: @Bob The drawings are corrected.

Comment: When you use symmetry on a diagram, you change the category in which it lives?

Comment: @Bob These diagrams all denote natural transformations between functors. We do everything in the same 2-category but we apply the symmetric reasoning. It's the same thing as applying the exact same reasoning but to a "symmetric" 2-category (for instance $\mathbf{Cat}^{\mathrm{co}}$ instead of $\mathbf{Cat}$). But here all the diagrams I drew live in the same 2-category.

Comment: @Bob Maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I thought your answer was a reformulation of the one by SCappella. But it cannot be the case because you stay in the same $2$-category **Cat**, while @SCappella goes through different categories (**Cat$^\text{co}$**, for example). So, if you were translating your answer without string diagrams you would have an argument that remains in **Cat**?

Comment: My answer is essentially a reformulation of SCappella's one. Here is a comparison: to prove for instance that coproducts are associative in a category, you can either use the fact that products are associative and apply it to the dual category, or you can apply the "dual reasoning" to your category directly, without ever mentioning the dual category. But these are two formulations of exactly the same thing.

Comment: Here, it is similar: I exposed the duality by putting side by side a construction and the dual construction (reverse left/right but not up/down). We can formulate exactly the same thing by using $\mathbf{Cat}^{\mathrm{co}}$ and saying that we do the construction in $\mathbf{Cat}^{\mathrm{co}}$. If we "unwind" the things, we end up with the same thing.

Comment: @Bob And yes, we can do an argument that remains in $\mathbf{Cat}$ (with or without string diagrams, these are just notations that can be translated into "inline" notation). These are different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but I finally chose @SCappella's one because it came first and received more votes from the crowd.

Comment: @Bob Ok, there's not problem with this! Thanks for taking the time to notify me!

Comment: I have a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382707   Could string diagrams enlighten me?

Comment: @Bob Hi. There is at least a way of visualizing the statement Zhen Lin quotes as the correct dualization using string diagrams. But in order to recover your statement as a formal dual of Zhen Lin's statement, you still need to show that the Kleisli category of a monad is a Kleisli object, and I'm not sure string diagrams would help for that.